# How can i use Firebase App distribution without google account?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-fabric, firebase-app-distribution

I am a **Fabric** user it works flawless for app distribution purpose. Recently I migrated my Fabric app to **Firebase** platform (as Google is removing Fabric) for app distribution with my testers. I followed their doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/ios/distribute-console and got email for app setup, but when I process it shows sign in with Google button. This is really useless how can my tester sign in without his google account as he only has our office domain email address?

I am unable to download with my domain email and can not share with our testers. How can I fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todd from Firebase. Right now it is mandatory that each tester has a Google account. This allows us to simplify the tester management process.

Comment: hey todd, are you considering to add other options anywhere in the future ?

Comment: Thanks for answer Todd, it would be great if your team consider adding other options  as well.

Comment: Hi todd, thanks for the answers. We are looking to use this in China to distribute our application. Firebase itself is said to work in China, however, I am afraid due to needing a google account the App Distribution feature will not be available there. Do you happen to know the state of this? Kind regards.

Comment: I like Firebase App Distribution, it works well for android users with (example@gmail.com) but for iOS users (who most likely have example@icloud.com) there are some issues!

If they don't have exmaple@gmail.com they have to create it (which is bad not everyone is ready to create gmail account while onboarding new testers just to try out my simple app) 

Any plans in near future to add ability for iOS testers to test app without example@gmail.com?

Comment: It's very strange that Firebase forces developers to force their beta testers to have a Google account. As a developer I already owe a tester for his time and willing to help. How can I tell him: **"Hey, to join a beta test, please create a google account, add your phone number and enable 2FA"**?

Comment: Hi Todd, I really need to download the apps using cli, not all testers are human

Comment: Is there any 2022 update to this? Is it possible to download apps without gmail account? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

**It is not solutions but to address the problem but to make question seen better!**

I like Firebase App Distribution, it works well for android users with (example@gmail.com) but for iOS users (who most likely have example@icloud.com) there are some issues!

If they don't have exmaple@gmail.com they have to create it (which is bad not everyone is ready to create gmail account while onboarding new testers just to try out my simple app)

> Any plans in near future to add ability for iOS testers to test app
> without example@gmail.com? To be able to use at least @icloud.com or facebook accounts

> Right now in App Center (microsoft alternative for firebase) there is a feature where you can deploy beta version for iOS/Android and users can use Github/Google/Microsoft/Facebook accounts to install beta apps

Answer (score -2):

You need to create google account with with google domain.

http://google.com/accounts/NewAccount

Comment: Great! You just have to clarify that you must create the account without a gmail.com domain, instead use the preferred account of any domain.